# polymer-cli install fails on Windows

Tags: git, npm, polymer

I'm trying to run `npm install -g polymer-cli@next` on Windows behind a corporate firewall. I was able to successfully install it on a Mac behind this same firewall, however Windows presented its own set of challenges. I have tried the following commands from both Git Bash and Windows Command Prompt.

At first I had a problem with `git@github.com:`  and `git://github.com/` urls not wanting to work.  I worked around that by adding the following items in `.gitconfig`

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git://github.com/
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

Once that issue was resolved a new one surfaced.  This file cannot be accessed even though it exists.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mckeejm\.npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-
PolymerElements-test-fixture-git-36a3c7ea\FETCH_HEAD
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\mckeejm\.npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-PolymerElements-test-fixture-git-36a3c7ea\FETCH_HEAD'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I thought at first it was a permissions issue and ran the following `npm config`commands to ensure that the current user would have access to the temp, cache, and prefix.

```
npm config set temp ~/.npm-temp --global
npm config set cache ~/.npm-cache --global
npm config set prefix ~/.npm-global
```

At this point it seems like a concurrency problem where the file is not done being downloaded by the time npm is looking for it.  I can't find a way to limit the concurrency of either `npm` or `git` that would affect this in a meaningful way.

That may not even be the issue, but we're totally stuck right now.  I can post the output of `npm config list` or `git config -l` but didn't want to bloat this question any further unless necessary.